# How can I write a standard notation for matrix of ones in mathematics [Example]?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, representation-theory, matrix-equations

Let $|Q|$ be denote magnitude of $Q$. A function $g$ that inverts the magnitude so that the maximum magnitude close to zeros. Hence it can be written as
$$g(|Q|)=\max(|Q|) 1_{Q}-|Q|$$
where $1_{Q}$ is unit matrix which consisting of all ones. It has same size with $Q$. The purpose for using it is to makes sense for the above subtraction ($\max(|Q|)$ returns a value, it cannot subtract to a matrix, then if I multiple it with matrix of one, it will be make sense)

For example, 
$$|Q|=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $\max (|Q|)=\max(1,2,..,12)=12$

The unit matrix is
$$1_Q=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Then the function $g$ has value
$$g(|Q|)=
        12\times \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}-        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 \\
        7 & 8 & 9 \\
        10 & 11 & 12 \\
        \end{bmatrix}=      
       \begin{bmatrix}
        11 & 10 & 9 \\
        8 & 7 & 6 \\
        5 & 4 & 3 \\
        2 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

However, my found that unit matrix must be square. Thus my denotation about matrix of ones looks mistake. Based on my example, could you suggest to me a clear equation for $g$ function in mathematics? Thanks